# What name to use when praying for baby in need of healing before it is born?

Tags: choleh-sick, baby-infant

Typically, when praying for someone in need of healing, we refer to them as "NAME ben/bat MOTHERS_NAME". For a baby before it is given a name, we can refer to them as "tinok ben/bat MOTHERS_NAME". How do we refer to a fetus before it is born? Or maybe do we just pray for the mother's healing (i.e. "MOTHERS_NAME ben/bat MOTHERS_MOTHERS_NAME")?

Comment: The Gemara Brachos 60A, Mishnah Berura 230:1 sent to indicate that the proper tefilla is to daven that the “vlad” be healthy, strong, upstanding and righteous, etc.